# Use class object referenced through WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf

Let me try to make this as simple to understand.

I have three components:

1. Class
2. WCF Service
3. Console application for testing

The class is your standard constructor/properties/fields/methods.
The WCF Service references the class.  One or more of its methods will return an object of the class.
The application references the WCF Service.  Application invokes method that will return object of class.

How do I use the class at the application level without referencing it directly?  Is there some code or attribute for the class that will permit this action?

Comment: Reference the shared assembly in your console application. Then, use "Share Types"

Comment: @JohnSaunders that wasn't really enough information to go on.  But I've resolved it in a very static fashion that I will be posting tomorrow once the 24 hour restriction has been lifted.